# Why am i getting a error trying to loop through href in selenium python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

The code i used for looping is given below. I tried to take the hrefs that are relevent to me by slicing the event_list to which all the hrefs are saved but im getting the error:

---> 35 print(event_links[16,:])
     36 
     37 #for link in event_links[16,:]:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Can i change the code in any way so that i can slice the list and how is that the list indices are tuples?

event_links = []

for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]"):

```
url = link.get_attribute('href')

event_links.append(url)
```

print(event_links[16,:])

Comment: Change `[16,:]` -> `[16:]`

Answer (score 0):

Tanzeem Alam:
First change [16,:] to [16:] , as indices are mentioned using colon ':' not comma ','.
To use list indices as tuples, you can use matrix format to store the list else you can numpy library of python to manipulate your array.